# Can I format my price of a product at the Model level in my Rails application so that it automatically formats as "$123.99"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want my output of product.price to be formatted properly, but I also don't want to add "number_to_currency(product.price, precision: 2)" everytime I reference the price in my ERB views templates. Is there a way to set this formatting at the Model level (i.e. in the Product class I'm defining here?)

What I tried:
I added `<%= number_to_currency(product.price, precision: 2) %>` everywhere in my ERB templates that I need to show the formatted price, which works, but I'm wondering if I can configure this formatting in the Model where I'm pulling the price from so I only have to set it once...

Edit: this is my product model:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  monetize :price_cents, numericality: true
  mount_uploader :image, ProductImageUploader

  belongs_to :category

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :price, presence: true
  validates :quantity, presence: true
  validates :category, presence: true
end
```

Comment: There's a lot of ways this could be done, e.g., a presenter/decorator, a model method that formats, a helper, ... A model method would be the **easiest** but not necessarily the **best** approach, but it depends.

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow.
As Dave says, we normally separate a model and this kind of code with the decorator pattern, but if you want a quick-and-dirty method in your model you can add something like:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
   # ... other model stuff goes here

   def price_display
      ActiveSupport::NumberHelper.number_to_currency(price, precision: 2)
   end
end
```